# win32: how stop ReadFile (stdin|pipe)

Tags: c++, winapi

I have handle that I got via `stdinHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` and I have separate thread which execute such code:

```
while (!timeToExit) {
  char ch;
  DWORD readBytes = 0;
  if (!::ReadFile(stdinHandle, &ch, sizeof(ch), &readBytes, nullptr)) {
    //report error
    return;
  }
  if (readBytes == 0)
      break;
  //handle new byte
}
```

where `timeToExit` is `std::atomic<bool>`.

I wan to stop this thread from another thread. I tried this:

```
timeToExit = true;
CloseHandle(stdinHandle);
```

and code hangs in `CloseHandle`.

The code hangs while program is running by other program that uses
`CreatePipe` and `DuplicateHandle` to redirect input of my program to pipe.

So how should I stop `while (!timeToExit)..` thread in win32 way?
Or may be I should some how change `while (!timeToExit)..` thread to make it possible
to stop it?

**Update**
I thought about usage of `WaitForMultipleObjects` before call of `ReadFile` with 
stdin and event as arguments, and trigger event in other thread,
but there is no mention of anonymous pipe as possible input  for `WaitForMultipleObjects`, plus I tried when stdin connected to console,
and it become useless (always return control without delay) after the first character typed into console,
looks like I have to use `ReadConsoleInput` in this case, instead of `ReadFile`?

Comment: `WaitForMultipleObjects()` can handle pipes named or unnamed and consoles as well.

Comment: @wilx `WaitForMultipleObjects` handles things in strange way, if process that run my program write 0 bytes to "piped" stdin, then it return (after the first call) `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, but `ReadFile` can not read even 1 byte, so I come back to problem mention in question, we have `ReadFile` waiting for input.

Comment: Don't write 0 bytes then?

Comment: @wilx I cann't, my application only which reading from stdin, program that run my program is external application. I have source code of it, but I doubt that I can merge any changes to it. And it doesn't write 0 byte, it cause `WAIT_OBJECT_0` event in some other way, but I not still get how. May be it is related to my x64 build vs x86 build of exteral program.

Comment: @wilx if run program from `cmd.exe` I got the same result - I haven't typed anything, but `WaitForMultipleObjects` return `WAIT_OBJECT_0`

Comment: @wilx external program (if it is not going to write something to stdin) and cmd.exe shared stdin with me, and `WaitFor` return control because of `INPUT_EVENT` with type `FOCUS_EVENT`. So I need some way to check console or pipe, and if it is console ignore all execept characters.

Comment: @fghj Your finding about `WaitForMultipleObjects` returning immediately on pipes is confirmed by the GHC source code [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ghc-8.2.1-release/libraries/base/cbits/inputReady.c#L180-L181).

Comment: I've posted a similar question: [How to CancelSynchronousIo() on WaitForSingleObject() waiting on stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336755/how-to-cancelsynchronousio-on-waitforsingleobject-waiting-on-stdin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When reading from a console's actual STDIN, you can use [`PeekConsoleInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684344.aspx) and [`ReadConsoleInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961.aspx) instead of `ReadFile()`.

When reading from an (un)named pipe, use [`PeekNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779.aspx) before calling `ReadFile()`.

This will allow you to poll STDIN for new input before actually reading it, and then you can check your thread termination status in between polls.

You can use [`GetFileType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960.aspx) to detect what kind of device is attached to your `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` handle.

Comment: Why is there one set of routines specifically for the console?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work - PeekNamedPipe() always returns 0, even if there are bytes that can be read.

Answer (score -2):

The safest way to do this would be to call [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) asynchronously (non-blocking) using the OVERLAPPED structure etc.  This can be done from your main thread.

If/when you need to cancel it, call [CancelIo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363791(v=vs.85).aspx) (from same thread that called ReadFile) or [CancelIoEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363792(v=vs.85).aspx) (if from another thread).

You might be able to make your current approach work; if you mark timeToExit as volatile, it may not hang, but that approach commonly creates bigger problems.

Comment: OVERLAPPED IO not working for console, or I missed something? For example in CreateFile msdn page there is special note for console about which flags are ignored, and you can not open stdin with overlapped flags. May be I missed something?