# How to CancelSynchronousIo() on WaitForSingleObject() waiting on stdin?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-console

On Windows 10, I'm waiting for input from the console using

[`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx)`( GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ... )`

and to cancel this waiting using [`CancelSynchronousIo()`](https://www.google.ch/search?q=CancelSynchronousIO&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=h7mEWZC7BOXI8gfx_IDADw).

But the cancellation does nothing (returns `0` and `GetLastError()` is `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`).

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? 
**Should I be able to cancel this waiting for new input on stdin?**

(I actually want to do this with any `HANDLE` whose [`GetFileType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960(v=vs.85).aspx) is `FILE_TYPE_CHAR`, not only stdin, but stdin is certainly the most important use case and the simplest to test with).

---

Related discussions I've found:

- [Synchronous ReadFile() on stdin cannot be unblocked by CancelSynchronousIo()](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dd7ce0e9-847d-4727-b0a6-efd68bd5626e/synchronous-readfile-on-stdin-cannot-be-unblocked-by-cancelsynchronousio?forum=windowssdk)
- [win32: how stop ReadFile (stdin|pipe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261889/win32-how-stop-readfile-stdinpipe)

But unfortunately they only discuss `ReadFile()`, not `WaitForSingleObject()`. I've also tried `WaitForMultipleObjects()` (with just a single object in the array), same problem.

(*Background: I'm trying to [improve input handling in the GHC Haskell compiler runtime](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8684).*)

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` is not I/O request and of course can not be canceled

Answer (score 3):

[`CancelSynchronousIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363794(v=vs.85).aspx) cancel I/O operations that are issued by the specified thread. more concrete it cancel [`IRP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550694(v=vs.85).aspx) packets which associated with specified thread via call [`IoCancelIrp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548338(v=vs.85).aspx). if use undocumented [`NtCancelSynchronousIoFile`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntioapi_8h_source.html#l01120) (`CancelSynchronousIo` internally call it with `IoRequestToCancel = 0`) we can be more selective - cancel only i/o request which used specified `IoRequestToCancel` (system check that `Irp->UserIosb == IoRequestToCancel` and cancel only this requests)

but `WaitForSingleObject` this is **not I/O request**. this call not create any `IRP` which can be canceled. so - no way do this.

however if you use [`WaitForSingleObjectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) with `bAlertable` set to `TRUE` - you can **break wait** by queue apc to thread by using [`QueueUserAPC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954(v=vs.85).aspx) . also if use [`NtWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567120(v=vs.85).aspx)  instead [`WaitForSingleObjectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) we can also alert thread by using undocumented call `NtAlertThread`. in this case [`NtWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567120(v=vs.85).aspx) will break with `STATUS_ALERTED` (note that [`WaitForSingleObjectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) which internally call [`NtWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567120(v=vs.85).aspx) do special check for `STATUS_ALERTED` and in case this status - again run [`NtWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567120(v=vs.85).aspx) - as result we can not break [`WaitForSingleObjectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) by call `NtAlertThread`, but [`NtWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567120(v=vs.85).aspx) will be breaked.

so if you need break waiting for std input - create additional thread, which must call not [`CancelSynchronousIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363794(v=vs.85).aspx) (this senseless) but [`QueueUserAPC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954(v=vs.85).aspx) or `NtAlertThread` (only if you use [`NtWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567120(v=vs.85).aspx) for wait). and input thread must wait in **alertable** state. so demo code can look like:

```
extern "C" NTSYSCALLAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI NtAlertThread(HANDLE ThreadHandle);

VOID NTAPI OnApc(ULONG_PTR Parameter)
{
    DbgPrint("OnApc(%p)\n", Parameter);
}

DWORD CALLBACK BreakWaitThread(HANDLE hThread)
{
    switch (LONG status = MessageBoxW(0, L"Use Apc(yes) or Alert(No) ?", L"BreakWaitThread", 
        MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_YESNOCANCEL|MB_DEFBUTTON3))
    {
    case IDYES:
        if (!QueueUserAPC(OnApc, hThread, 0))
        {
            DbgPrint("QueueUserAPC=%u\n", GetLastError());
        }
        break;
    case IDNO:
        if (0 > (status = NtAlertThread(hThread)))
        {
            DbgPrint("AlertThread=%x\n", status);
        }
        break;
    case IDCANCEL:
        DbgPrint("canceled\n");
        break;
    default:
        DbgPrint("MessageBox=%x\n", status);
    }

    CloseHandle(hThread);

    return 0; 
}

void ConsoleLoop(HANDLE hStdIn)
{
    ULONG NumberOfEvents, NumberOfEventsRead, n;

    INPUT_RECORD buf[8], *p;

    for (;;)
    {
        switch (ZwWaitForSingleObject(hStdIn, TRUE, 0))
        //switch (WaitForSingleObjectEx(hStdIn, INFINITE, TRUE))
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

            while (GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(hStdIn, &NumberOfEvents) && NumberOfEvents)
            {
                do 
                {
                    NumberOfEventsRead = min(RTL_NUMBER_OF(buf), NumberOfEvents);

                    if (ReadConsoleInput(hStdIn, buf, NumberOfEventsRead, &NumberOfEventsRead) && NumberOfEventsRead)
                    {
                        n = NumberOfEventsRead;
                        p = buf;
                        do 
                        {
                            if (p->EventType == KEY_EVENT)
                            {
                                DbgPrint("%u(%u) %C %x %x %x\n", 
                                    p->Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown,
                                    p->Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount,
                                    p->Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar,
                                    p->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode,
                                    p->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode,
                                    p->Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState);

                                if (VK_OEM_PERIOD == p->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
                                {
                                    return ;//if user type '.' return for demo
                                }
                            }
                        } while (p++, --n);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hStdIn);
                        break;
                    }

                } while (NumberOfEvents -= NumberOfEventsRead);
            }
            continue;

        case STATUS_USER_APC:
            DbgPrint("\nUSER_APC\n");
            return;
        case STATUS_ALERTED:
            DbgPrint("\nALERTED\n");
            return;
        case WAIT_FAILED :
            DbgPrint("\nWAIT_FAILED=%u\n", GetLastError());
            return;
        default:
            __debugbreak();
            return;
        }
    }
}

void SimpleDemo()
{
    if (HANDLE hCurrentThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALERT|THREAD_SET_CONTEXT , FALSE, GetCurrentThreadId()))
    {
        ULONG dwThreadId;
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, BreakWaitThread, hCurrentThread, 0, &dwThreadId);

        if (hThread)
        {
            ConsoleLoop(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
            PostThreadMessage(dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        else
        {
            CloseHandle(hCurrentThread);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed reply and background information!

Answer (score 2):

Console I/O is difficult to use asynchronously, it is simply not designed for it. See [IO Completion Ports (IOCP) and Asynchronous I/O through STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR](http://always-learning.timmcnamara.nz/iocp-and-stdio/) for some possible workarounds.

If that is not an option for you, then you will have to either:

1. use `WaitForSingleObject()` in a loop with a short timeout.  Create a flag variable that your loop can look at on each iteration to break the loop if the flag is set.
2. use `WaitForMutipleObjects()`, giving it 2 `HANDLE`s to wait on - one for the console (or whatever), and one for an event object from `CreateEvent()`.  Then you can signal the event with `SetEvent()` when you want to break the wait.  The return value of `WaitForMutipleObjects()` will tell you which `HANDLE` was signaled.

Comment: console have different implementations in different windows versions. before win8 - console handles - not file handles, as result asynchronous i/o can not be used on it. however begin from win 8 (or 8.1) implementation changed - now this is real file handles, which can be opened in asynchronous mode too (`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` not ignored despite in msdn this not stated) and formal we can easy use async i/o on console too in win 8/10.

Comment: @RbMm, the "\Device\ConDrv" back-end communication channel that's used by the console host in Windows 8+ does allow canceling synchrononous I/O via `CancelSynchronousIo`, like any other standard NT I/O device, but the console's I/O loop that calls `NtDeviceIoControlFile` doesn't support canceling a cooked read from `ReadFile` or `ReadConsoleW`. The client-side request gets canceled, but the console is left in a cooked read that gets thrown away once the user presses enter. It's best to avoid canceling synchronous console I/O until this bug is addressed (if ever).

Comment: @eryksun - yes. interesting. we can cancel client i/o request (synchronous or asynchronous(via CancelIo[Ex]) - no matter), but after this need 2 time press enter in console window - first user input(enter) will be lost and only second processed as well. however i say not about this. simply note that we can open asynchronous console handle since win8+ and use asynchronous read (nothing say about cancel it). and of course wait function can not be canceled as io request

Comment: Thanks for this. I will first try to implement option (2), as it seems the cleanest and easiest.

Comment: @nh2 - option (2) is very near use alertable wait via `WaitForSingleObjectEx` - you create event handle or open handle for thread which will be wait. pass this handle to another ("break") thread. and when you want break wait - you or signal event, or queue apc to thread. also when (based on which event) you can try break wait on *conin$* ? may be better just wait on this even and on console at once via `WaitForMutipleObjectsEx` or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` ?

Comment: @RbMm: explicit event or alertable event, it doesn't really matter. The end effect is the same. Just make sure unwanted threads are not alerting the thread unexpectedly. I prefer using an explicit event

Comment: yes, agree. however i will be ask - based on which "event" op can decide break wait ? may be exist sense just wait on this "event" / signal simultaneously with *conin$* in single wait call

Comment: @RbMm: That is what I said in my answer. Pass them both to the wait function, and it will return which one satisfied the wait. If the console, read the input. If the event, stop waiting